# Partition a set of variables into a subset with factor structure and another without

Tags: factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

Suppose a data matrix $\underset{n\times p}{X}$ can be partitioned into $\underset{n\times k}{X_1}$ and $\underset{n\times (p-k)}{X_2}$.
$X_1$ has an underlying factor structure with an unknown, low number of factors $m$, perhaps $m=2$ or $m=3$.
If $n=300$, $p=80$, $20\leq k \leq 60$ and $k$ is unknown, what strategy could be adopted to find the partition into subsets $X_1$ and $X_2$?

Brute force would take all possible combinations of 20, 21, ..., 60 columns and see if 2 or 3 factors yield an adequate description of the data. That would be quite computationally expensive, I think. I am wondering if a smarter way towards the goal exists.

It is not very important that the partitioning is done very precisely; a couple of columns could be misassigned to $X_1$ vs. $X_2$ if this allows for a significant gain in computational efficiency.